# Memory allocation in C vs Java

Tags: java, c, memory, integer

I am trying to find if a number is even or odd without using Modulus operation. According to my understanding, when I define an int in C or in Java , that number is stored as 64 bytes of memory. I can access Zeroth(0th) bit of that number using square bracket[].

However, I am not able to do it in Java.

So, my question is how memory allocation and syntax is different in Java ?

Comment: `boolean isEven = (num & 1) == 0;`

Comment: `boolean isEven = (num % 2) == 0;`

Answer (score 2):

This really is nothing to do with "memory" or "memory allocation".  You're talking about a simple property of a number.

In binary, the least significant bit of a number is 1 if the number is odd, or 0 if the number is even.   OK, so how do we isolate the bottom bit?  The answer is the 'and' operation, expressed in both C and Java as '&'.

```
  boolean isEven = (number & 1) == 0;  
  boolean isOdd = (number & 1) != 0;
```

By the way, in C

- An integer certainly does not occupy 64 bytes. Maybe 64 bits, depending on computer, C implementation, etc.
- Given a single integer, brackets don't give you bit-level access. Brackets are for array indexing: i.e., picking out the N'th number in an array of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access memory in Java like you can in C

You can, however, use the bit wise `&` operator to pick out one or more bits of the integer value.  If you do it for the bit corresponding to even/odd and see if the result is zero or not, you will have your answer without using modulo

Answer (score 0):

You can’t access individual bits in an integer type in C *or* Java using the `[]` operator. The operand of the `[]` operator must be an array type (C and Java) or a pointer type (C).

Integer types in C and Java behave similarly, although integer types in Java have a fixed size (C integer types have a *minimum* size).  In both languages, integer types are allocated the same way.

As for testing odd/even integers without using bitwise operations (which may have endianness issues) or the modulus operator, you can take advantage of integer arithmetic.

In both C and Java, dividing an integer by an integer gives an integer result.  `3/2 == 1`, not `1.5`.  `100/26 == 3`, etc.  So, if you divide the original value by 2, then multiply that result by 2, you’ll get the original value back only if the original value is even:

```
3 / 2 == 1, 1 * 2 == 2, 2 != 3 
4 / 2 == 2, 2 * 2 == 4, 4 == 4
5 / 2 == 2, 2 * 2 == 4, 4 != 5
```

You get the idea.  So,

```
int tmp = x / 2;
if ( x == tmp * 2 )
  // x is even
else
  // x is odd
```

Comment: I don't think there's any endian issues.  In ```(number & 1)``` both ```number``` and ```1``` are integers that possess a 'least significant bit". That particular bit may be in the lowest-numbered byte of the integer in memory or it may be in the highest-numbered byte of the integer.  Either way, it's the same relative byte for both of them, and the result is always one of the bit-patterns we designate as 0 or 1.  But the divide-and-multiple approach is good info anyway.